# Como escrever um pseudocódigo?

Tags: pseudocódigo

Estava lendo sobre algoritmos, mas todos os algoritmos que lia, era escrito em alguma linguagem desconhecida ou não inventada, mas de certa maneira conseguia entender o que estava escrito ali.

Eu li a respeito sobre o [Portugol](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugol), uma "linguagem" escrita em português que foi feita apenas para ser interpretada pelo ser humano, esse seria um olá mundo:

```
Algoritmo "OlaMundo"
var
inicio
Escreval("Olá, Mundo!")
Fimalgoritmo
```

Nesse código acima, não entendo o que é esse `var` perdido no meio do caminho, e isso me causou certa confusão.

Minha dúvida é: como escrever corretamente um pseudocódigo, para que todos programadores consigam entender o que estou tentando interpretar? Existe uma sintaxe definida para isso? Posso escrever como quiser, de tal maneira que consiga entender?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Até onde sei, não existe uma regra para escrever um pseudocódigo, logo não existe uma maneira *correta* para escrevê-lo, ele apenas deve ser escrito de maneira simples, fazendo com que qualquer pessoa com conhecimentos mínimos em programação possa entendê-lo.

Nota que mesmo utilizando convenções de uma linguagem de programação normal, o pseudocódigo destina-se exclusivamente para a *leitura humana*.

Na [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoc%C3%B3digo) temos a seguinte definição:

> **Pseudocódigo** é uma forma genérica de escrever um algoritmo, utilizando uma linguagem simples (*nativa a quem o escreve, de forma a ser entendida por qualquer pessoa*) sem necessidade de conhecer a sintaxe de nenhuma linguagem de programação.

Com relação ao trecho de código escrito em portugol, o `var` identifica a seção para declaração das variáveis que o programa irá utilizar.
No exemplo em questão, o `var` poderia ser omitido sem problema algum, o código compila normalmente no [Visualg](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualg).

Answer (score 11):

Pseudo : "Prefixo usado na formação de palavras para exprimir falsidade ou semelhança".

Um pseudocódigo imita um código real, mas não é. Ele é uma representação de um algorítimo,que por sua vez : "... é uma sequência finita de instruções bem definidas e não ambíguas...".

Cada um pode escrever seu próprio pseudo-código para sua própria finalidade, mas aqui estamos falando de um algorítimo que tenta imitar um programa que será executado por um interpretador/compilador x, que possue sua própria regra de sintaxe e semântica para definir as ações a serem realizadas.

No exemplo que coloca poderíamos traduzir do pseudo-código (Portugol), para a língua portuguesa assim:

```
Algoritmo "OlaMundo"{Define o nome do algorítimo como OlaMundo}
var{palavra chave para declarar uma ou mais variáveis nesse caso está vazio é desnecessário e confunde mesmo, se o VisualG precisar disso vazio eu vejo como erro}
inicio{palavra chave para marcar o inicio do algorítimo}
Escreval("Olá, Mundo!"){Escreva na tela Olá, Mundo!}
Fimalgoritmo{palavra chave para marcar o fim do algorítimo}
```

O algorítimo real em `PHP` por exemplo seria:

```
<?php
$variavel = "Olá, Mundo!";//Atribuo a variável uma string Olá, Mundo! 
echo $variavel;//echo é o comando que emite a string passada como argumento
?>
```

Toda linguagem possui sua documentação, contendo sua regras.

O [VisualG](http://www.netsoft.inf.br/aulas/4_ECI_Introducao_a_Informatica/Visualg2_manual.pdf) é baseado no Portugol, veja sua documentação.

Answer (score 9):

Vamos a algumas definições antes de realmente responder.

Segundo [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoc%C3%B3digo):

> **Pseudocódigo** é uma forma genérica de escrever um algoritmo, utilizando uma linguagem simples (nativa a quem o escreve, de forma a
>   ser entendida por qualquer pessoa) sem necessidade de conhecer a
>   sintaxe de nenhuma linguagem de programação.

Um exemplo utilizado em instituições de ensino, é o compilador [Visualg](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualg), do qual facilita a ilustração de um algoritmo, de forma que todos os programadores possam entendê-los (independentemente da linguagem que utilizem).

Na minha época aprendi em Pascal, que no caso é, como se fosse o portugol da língua inglesa que se assemelham bastante a um pseudocódigo.

**Pascal:**

```
program OlaMundo;
begin
 WriteLn('Olá, Mundo!');
end.
```

**Visualg:**

```
Algoritmo "OlaMundo"
inicio
Escreval("Olá, Mundo!")
Fimalgoritmo
```

O exemplo que postou acredito que seja em visualg, e adota o `var`, para declaração de variáveis, pois o visualg precisa de alguma forma interpretar para conseguir compilar, mas se tratando de pseudocódigo, não compilável, o intuito é compreender o que esta tentando ser transmitido, outro exemplo:

```
INÍCIO
VARIÁVEIS
S,C,I,A,MD:Real;
S ← 0;
C ← 0;
PARA I de 1 ATÉ 10 FAÇA PASSO 1
    Escreva "Digite um número: ";
    LEIA A;
    SE A ≥ 0 ENTÃO
         S ← S + A;
         C ← C + 1;
    FIM SE;
FIM PARA;
MD ← S / C;
ESCREVER ("A média é: ", MD);
FIM
```

**Conclusão:**
Assim, não importa a sintaxe que vai utilizar para escrever, com um minino de padrão, e desde seja possível o receptor entender o que esta querendo ser dito, é válido.